# Почему curl делает 2 запроса подряд?

Tags: php, curl

Ребят, помогите пожалуйста, я просто уже не понимаю почему так происходит.

Вообщем я на свой же сайт отправляю тестовый запрос, а curl отправляет 2 запроса. 
Тоисть когда curl отправляет запрос на мою страницу, то в бд должно добавиться +1 значение, но вместо 1, он добавляет 2, значит curl делает 2 запроса. Как это исправить ? Почему так происходит ?

файл index.php

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://test.ru/test.php",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
        'test' => 1,
    ],
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
]);

$results = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $results;
```

файл test.php

```
if (!empty($_POST['test'])) {

    cRow("UPDATE `settings` SET `balance` = `balance` + 1 WHERE `id` = :id", [
        'id' => 1,
    ]);

    exit('success');

} else {
    exit('Ошибка!');
}
```

Comment: Проблему решил, проблема была из за htaccess файла, удалил строки:

Comment: Не надо в комментарии писать, в __ответе__ напишите.

Answer (score 0):

может быть кому-нибудь поможет, у меня проблема была в том что не был настроен нормально nginx

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е.браузер сам запрашивает favicon и из-за этого получается два запроса, в конфигурацию сайта в nginx добавил

```
location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}
```

это решило проблему